# How to create multiple simple-products with same SKU in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce, sku

I want to create multiple simple-product with same SKU in WooCommerce.
I search in admin settings but there I cannot find any settings to enable this features. Is there any hook so I can disable this features.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> If you want to completely disable the SKU feature then you have to use
>   [`wc_product_sku_enabled`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_product_sku_enabled.html) filter. It will remove the SKU field from both
>   backend and frontend.

```
add_filter( 'wc_product_sku_enabled', '__return_false' );
```

---

> If you want to keep the SKU feature but need to disable *unique SKU
>   check* then you have to use [`wc_product_has_unique_sku`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_product_has_unique_sku.html) filter. It
>   will keep the SKU field in both backend and frontend, but will allow
>   you to add multiple duplicate SKU.

```
add_filter( 'wc_product_has_unique_sku', '__return_false' );
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme). Or also in any plugin php files.*
Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello sir, 
Thanks for your reply, but i resolved the problem by using the below filter.
add_filter( 'wc_product_has_unique_sku', '__return_false' );

Comment: Thanks @dineshkashera coz of you I got to know `wc_product_has_unique_sku` filter. I have updated my answer with that. This question is very helpful for the community.

Comment: Note that doing this means you will get an unpredictable output from get_product_id_by_sku() - it is limited to one result and not filterable. This affects things like the [add_to_cart] shortcode and the API.

Comment: Something I've noticed is that the product importer will now not upload the duplicate sku products. Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Comment: @richplane Just thought that I'd add that `get_product_id_by_sku()` (used by `wc_get_product_id_by_sku()`) is filterable now. Filter: [`woocommerce_get_product_id_by_sku`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-data-stores-class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.html#source-view.1023)