# Update WooCommerce products programmatically

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I'm currently migrating data from a custom CMS over to WooCommerce. I'm able to create the products fine using the following code:

```
try {
    $product = new WC_Product_Variable();
    $product->set_name($productData["Name"]);
    $product->set_description($productData["Description"]);
    $product->set_price($productData["Price"]);
    $product->set_sku("PW" . $productData["ID"]);
    $product->set_category_ids($productData["NewCategoryIds"]);
    $product->set_status($productData["OnlineStatus"]);

...
```

The problem I'm having though is that when I re-run my script, I get `WC_Data_Exception: Invalid or duplicated SKU`.

This is odd, because when looking at the save function within the `WC_Product_Variable` class, the comment says:

> Save data (either create or update depending on if we are working on an existing product).

... but the save function within that class doesn't appear to do any updating.

Comment: By default SKU is unique per product in Woocommerce, You have either to disable SKU for products or allow duplicate SKU, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41585021/5638658) for more information.

Comment: I need the SKU keeping. I just want to be able to update a product if it already exists, otherwise - create it.

Comment: Try to use the function `wc_get_product_id_by_sku($sku)` to check if the product exist then update it or create a new one if not